# Rspec method similar to MiniTest 'assert'

Tags: ruby, rspec, automated-tests

There is some talk at work here of changing from MiniTest to Rspec (with Ruby, obviously) for writing test automation. I *really* liked MiniTest's ability to `assert` web elements since it would tell me at the end about failures i.e., `assert $b.link(:text => 'DAM').present?` 
Does Rspec have something equivalent to this? I'd like to matain this style as it's less lines of code to write out if possible

Comment: http://rspec.info/ <= Everything you'll ever need to know about Rspec

Comment: of course it has! and it is `expect(something).to`...

Comment: Link to documentation: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rspec uses expect() in a similar way to Minitest's assert.  `expect(actual).to eq(expected)`  You can get in depth with the docs at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/ .   Note that there are few different ways to test the truth in Rspec(from https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers):

```
expect($b.link(:text => 'DAM').present?).to be true      # passes if actual == true
expect($b.link(:text => 'DAM').present?).to eq true    # passes if actual == true
expect($b.link(:text => 'DAM').present?).to be_truthy    # passes if actual is truthy (not nil or false)
```

If you spend a lot of time in rspec, you can also create custom matchers for common tests that extend the use of "be" e.g.

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_present do
  match do |actual|
    actual.present?
  end
end

expect($b.link(:text => 'DAM')).to be_present      # passes if $b.link(:text => 'DAM').present? == true
```

Comment: Thanks, @Tim Mulry--I read the info for using `expect`, but the more in-depth look was what I needed, for sure

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Minitest's assertions with RSpec, you can configure it to do so:

http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/expectation-framework-integration/configure-expectation-framework#configure-minitest-assertions